# How to find open ports on goDaddy Dedicated server?

Tags: .net

I have written a program in DotNet which listens to a port and stores the data received in a database. The code runs fine on local machine, but, when I deploy the code to Go Daddy dedicated server with Dedicated IP, no data is received and stored in the database. It seems that the port on which data is send is closed because I get an error message that the connection cannot be established. Which port number should I use to send data on Go Daddy dedicated server? GoDaddy won't tell me about the open ports on the Dedicated server. Is there any way to find out the open ports on GoDaddy server which I can use to send data.

Comment: I think this is more suitable for ServerFault. Anyway, on a Dedicated server you should be in control of the firewall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically hosting providers only allow a limited set of open ports 80 for HTTP, 443 for HTTPS etc. Unless you have a dedicated server with a hosting provider it is unlikely that the provider will open other arbitrary ports for you.

You can prove the above statement by port scanning your host: http://nmap.org/nmap_doc.html - be aware your hosting provider might consider this to be rude / offensive.

I would recommend making your service a web service, this will then be able to use port 80, which is always open, and it will co-exist alongside your website without interfering with it. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8wbhsy70(v=vs.80).aspx

You should be able to use your existing code and simply expose it as a web service.

Remember to add appropriate security to your web service to avoid spammers filling your database with rubbish.